# How to find if an object is facing another object given position and direction as separate vectors

Tags: mathematics, software-engineering, vector

I found a very helpful post about exactly what I need [here](http://nic-gamedev.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-vector-mathematics-dot-products.html). It uses dot products to which is what I'm specifically looking for.

It talks about players facing monsters basically. They give a helpful picture here, [image]

My question though, is what if you have a function with 3 arguments: the position of object 1, the position of object 2, and the direction object 1 is facing given as a unit vector. So the picture would look as so:

[image]

How would you find whether A is facing B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you mean by "A is facing B", but you can use the same approach mentioned in the link you give.  The other vector to examine (in addition to the direction `A` is facing) is the one connecting and pointing from `A` to `B` (calculated by `B-A`).

Your code would be something like.

```
facing = dotProduct(normalize(B-A), normalize(directionFacingOfA))
```

Which will give you the cosine of the angle between where `A` is facing, and the vector where `A` faces `B`.  Pretty easy.  Three possibilities:

1. If `A` faces `B` almost perfectly (angle close to 0), `facing` will be close to 1 (`cos(0)`).
2. If `A` isn't facing *away* from `B`, `facing` will be between 0 and 1. It is up to you to decide if this is "close enough".
3. If `A` **is** facing away from `B`, `facing` will be negative.

This approach works for either 2D or 3D.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. It seemed to work in my program. Question though. I've posted a link to a picture I drew. I'm not quite sure how the dot product of those two equate to which way A is facing. Could you maybe explain it a little more.

http://i.imgur.com/8AtzUFQ.png

Comment: isn't it at (3,7)?

Comment: OH I'm sorry, I drew it wrong. Hold on

Comment: Actually, I take that back again. Yea, A is (3,7). But the direction vector is a separate argument, which would be (0,-1)

Comment: In your picture, B-A is incorrect.   B-A yields a vector that if you put the tail on A, it points to B.  In your picture, B-A = (2, -16), a vector pointing down and to the right.

Comment: http://electron9.phys.utk.edu/vectors/images/positi1.gif

Shouldn't the tail of B-A start at the tail of B?

Comment: Vectors have no inherent position.  *If* you take B-A, and put its tail on A, it will point to B.  That is the relative vector we need to determine facing.  You compute B-A like so (B.x - A.x, B.y - A.y, B.z - A.z).  Easy.  For your 2D vector, (2, -16) is the general directional vector from A to B.  Normalize it, and dot it with A's facing, and you know how close they are together.